# How to test a PyQt5 QApplication using pytest and pytest-qt?

Tags: python, qt, testing, pyqt5, pytest-qt

I am trying to test my QtApplication using pytest-qt and need some assistance with the basics.

Give a simple mwe such as this:

```
# mwe.py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QToolTip,
    QPushButton, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()
        self.count = 0


    def initUI(self):

        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 10))

        self.setToolTip('This is a <b>QWidget</b> widget')

        btn = QPushButton('Button', self)
        btn.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget')
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.move(50, 50)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.pushedTheButton)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Tooltips')
        self.show()

    def pushedTheButton(self):
        print("Button pressed")
        self.count += 1


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How would I test that the counter has incremented when the button is pressed?

```
from mwe import Example
import pytest
import pytestqt
from pytestqt.qtbot import QtBot
import sys

from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication

def test_press_button(qtbot: QtBot):
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()

    qtbot.add_widget(ex)
    sys.exit(app.exec())
    
    # how to press the button and verify that counter is incermented?
```

Note, I've been able to do this outside the main loop, by just instantiating the `Example` but for my integration testing I want to have the full application open and running.

Thanks in advance!